# In tree view how to display data/ Content in right side by selecting Child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, bootstrapper

I am using MVC application.

Please find below tree view structure.

```
Company Maintenance
  -Employees
  -Reports
     Report1
     Report2
     Report3
-Employee Maint.
     CSE
     IT
     ECE
     CSE
     Human Resources.
```

I am using jquery and html to display above tree view, and the `.CSHTML` code is as follows:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30%">
      <ul id="tree1">
        <li>
          <a href="#">TECH</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Company Maintenance</li>
            <li>Employees</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Reports
          <ul>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#report1" >Report1 </a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#report1" >Report2 </a> </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#report1" >Report3 </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Employee Maint.    
          <ul>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#cse"> CSE </a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#it"> IT </a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#eee"> EEE</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#ece">ECE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Human Resources</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="report1" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <p> Report 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="report2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <p> Report 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="report3" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <p> Report 3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="cse" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <p> CSE</p>
        </div>
        <div id="it" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <p> IT</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ece" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <p> ECE</p>
        </div>
        <div id="eee" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Details</h3>
          <p> EEE</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here I am using hyperlinks in Anchor tag to display content on right side. But these links are not working properly. When I click/ Select on Report 1 the report1 details should be displayed on right side.

1) Selected Report 1:     Report1 Details displayed

2) Next Select Report2:  Report2 Details displayed

3) Next Select CSE :         CSE details displayed

4) Next Select Company Maintaince:  Details of Company Maintaince displayed

5) Next Select Report1: Report1 details displayed

6) Next Select Company Maintaince:  Here details of Company Maintaince  are not displayed. The link is not working

7) Next Select Human Resource:  HR infor has been displayed

8) Then  Select Company Maintaince:  Details of Company Maintaince displayed.

then Links are not properly working. why?? Are there is any other way to display data/ Content in right side by selecting nodes in tree view as explained above???
    Can some one help me how to achieve this.

Regards,
    Gousiya

Comment: You can use a plugin like https://www.jstree.com/docs/html/